# How to share Threads in C# Properly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I built an OCR application which reads PDF files and OCR's them. I built it using Multi-threading with the Parallel.ForEach function.

This works brilliantly, but I noticed that the way the threads are divided seems to work differently to what I'm expecting.

**Scenario**: When allocating only 10 threads using **MaxDegreeOfParallelism**, it divides the workload and I can see 10 threads being immediately started. However, there are 100 items that needs to be processed. When it gets around 80/100 items processed, it slows down by only running 2 out of the 10 threads. I suspect this is due to 8/10 threads have successfully completed their portion of the work, but because some PDFs took longer on a certain thread, that thread is still processing his portion of the work.

So my question is, how can I write this better so that even if it does get to 80/100, there should ALWAYS be 10 active threads... (of course when it gets to 90+ the threads will die down, but at least it wont process 1 by 1 when the last thread still has workload to complete.

I hope this makes sense. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(F.files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = iNumberOfThreads }, items =>
{
    //do work here
}
});
```

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is meant for data parallelism, not executing multiple independent tasks concurrently. Its job is to partition the input data into as many partitions as there are cores and use *one task* for each partition. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` refers to the number of partitions, not threads

Comment: Instead of `Parallel.ForEach` use `ActionBlock<T>` with the DOP you want.

Comment: If you always want 10 active threads, then create 10 threads explicitly. The benefit of using a method such as `Parallel.ForEach` and the TPL is that you don't have to care about the actual number of threads being involved. The TPL takes care of this for you by scaling the degree of concurrency dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos, I've implemented `ActionBlock<T>`, which resolves my problem.

```
var getData = new ActionBlock<JsonPDFReader.File>(items =>
{
    //Code Here

}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = iNumberOfThreads });

foreach (JsonPDFReader.File items in F.files)
{
    getData.Post(items);
}
getData.Complete();
getData.Completion.Wait();
```